# Rock star. Is it a metaphor?

Tags: metaphors

Is "rock star" in this context a metaphor?

> This is (a specific tour) the rock star of all Britain and Ireland vacations.

Comment: _Star_ is a metaphor. The various kinds (_movie star, rock star, rising star, porn star_) just indicate the category of "star" they belong to.

Comment: @JohnLawler But calling something a "rock star" when it has nothing to do with rock-and-roll music is an additional level of metaphor.

Comment: Yes. Just like calling an especially capable person a "Swiss Army man". Metaphors nest and spread like fungi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a metaphor.

The normal meaning of "star" is a very famous performer. Rock stars are stars in the field of rock-and-roll music.

Since rock stars are some of the most famous people in the world, the phrase is often used as a metaphor when someone else is treated or admired like such a celebrity.

It's usually used to refer to people, but the metaphor can be stretched to other famous things. Although in my opinion they've gone a bit too far in using it to describe a vacation tour.